# Ruby grep not filtering out non-matching inputs

Tags: ruby

Given I have this class:

```
class A
  attr_accessor :a, :b, :c, :d
end
```

Given these are the instance methods:

```
A.instance_methods(false)
 => [:a, :a=, :b, :b=, :c, :c=, :d, :d=]
```

I try to filter out any item in array with an "=":

```
A.instance_methods(false).grep(/[^=]/)
 => [:a, :a=, :b, :b=, :c, :c=, :d, :d=] 

 A.instance_methods(false).grep(/[a-zA-Z]/)
 => [:a, :a=, :b, :b=, :c, :c=, :d, :d=]
```

But it does not filter out the items with a "=". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: All the symbols you listed match your regular expressions.  That's why it's not working.  they all have something that isn't an equal sign and they all match something that is a lower or upper case letter.

Comment: _"I try to filter out any item in array with an ="_ – do you really want to filter out all method names containing a `=` or just setters? What's your goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add anchors to the regex:

```
class A
  attr_accessor :a, :b, :c, :d
end

p A.instance_methods(false)
p A.instance_methods(false).grep(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/)  # [1]
p A.instance_methods(false).grep(/[^=]$/)        # [2]
```

Output:

```
[:d, :a=, :b=, :b, :c=, :a, :c, :d=]
[:d, :b, :a, :c]
[:d, :b, :a, :c]
```

As pointed out by [Dan Farrell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1726083/dan-farrell), your regexes are too broad and match anything that "doesn't have an `=`" or "has an alpha character", respectively. Adding the anchors narrows the match to "one or more alpha only" in `[1]` and "doesn't end in an `=` character" in `[2]`.

Comment: `^.*` is pointless in this regex.  I suggest you remove it.  We  only want to match things that don't end in `=`, that's easy enough: `/[^=]$/`.  No need to additionally say that they must start with 0 or more characters; that goes without saying.

Answer (score 5):

> I try to filter out any item in array with an "=".

In this type of filtering you may want to use [`grep_v`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep_v) instead, which is the inverse of `grep`. It removes anything that matches the regular expression.

Now your expression becomes simple:

```
[:a, :a=, :b, :b=, :c, :c=, :d, :d=].grep_v(/=/)
=> [:a, :b, :c, :d]
```